# The specific name of the formula $x^T Ay$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $x$ and $y$ are column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. What is the specific name of the formula $x^T A y$ where $T$ is for transposition?

Comment: I don't think that this scalar has a name. If $A$ were symmetric I might call $x^TAy=1$ the polar equation of $x^TAx=1$.

Comment: If you consider this as a function of $x$ and $y$, where $A$ is fixed, then this is the bilinear form given by $A$.

Comment: @tomasz One has to assume $A$ is **symmetric**. Otherwise expression $x^TAy$ has no interest.

Comment: @JeanMarie: No, there is no need to assume that. $A$ is symmetric if and only if the corresponding bilinear form is symmetric, but bilinear forms do not have to be symmetric to be of interest.

Comment: @tomasz All right, I will set it into a different form : I am pretty sure that in more than 99% of cases, expressions $x^TAy$ occur with a *symmetric* $A$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm pretty sure that hermitian or skew-symmetric $A$s occur in much more than 1% of the cases.

Comment: Granted, the hermitian $A$ is more likely to occur in $\bar x^TAy$ or $x^TA\bar y$.

Comment: Regardless, just stating outright that they are of no interest is an unfair generalisation. Studying these expressions is interesting even if you are eventually only interested in symmetric bilinear forms, in order to develop the basic theory of bilinear forms.